# Issue with passing variables based on variables

Tags: html, reactjs

```
<input type="radio" id="red" name="colour" value="red" required defaultChecked={memoInfo.colour == "red"} />
```

`memoInfo.colour == "red"` returns `true` when logged in console (literally the line before the code above is rendered with the input tag). If I replace the condition statement with simply a hardcoded `true`, it works. Why doesn't my condition statement within work then?

Comment: Try   defaultChecked={memoInfo.colour === "red"} and let me know  - it works for you or not.

Comment: If it doesn't work please share a component code. So, we can review and help you out.

Comment: Hi Maulik, unfortunately, it didn't work. Here's the code for the entire component – https://hastebin.skyra.pw/amajuqamoq.ts